# Stopping condition for MCTS

Tags: hypothesis-testing, monte-carlo, probability-generating-fn

I'm trying to come up with a stopping condition for [MCTS with exploration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search#Exploration_and_exploitation). Say we have $m$ actions at the root state, and after $N$ playouts they have $n_1\geq ...\geq n_m$ visits. I want to test the null hypothesis that after $k$ more playouts, $n_1'\geq n_i'$ for all $i$, where $n_i'$ is the new visit count of action $i$.

So far I tried assuming the selection probability for the next $k$ playouts is a constant $p_i$ and noting that $$E[x_1^{n_1'}+...+x_m^{n_m'}]=x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_m^{n_m}(p_1x_1+...+p_mx_m)^k$$

and then if I plug in $x_1=\frac1{x_2\cdots x_m}$ my answer should be the sum of coefficients of terms without negative exponents, but I don't know how to continue from here. Can anyone help me?

Are there other stopping conditions for finding the most-visited action in MCTS?

Comment: How did you go with this? UCT is the Upper Confidence bound - can this be used as the stopping condition?

Comment: I think I ended up calculating the CDF of some multinomial distribution. Also in hindsight I'm not sure I formulated the null hypothesis correctly lol. How would you suggest using UCT as a stopping condition? Isn't it just a rule to select the next node?